# compojure defroutes - route sometimes not recognized

Tags: clojure, compojure

I have a clojure / compojure webapp with the following routes

```
(defroutes my-routes
 (GET "/app/preview" request  (my-preview-function request))
 (ANY "*" request (str "ANY page <br>" (request :params))))
```

The preview GET request is made with a couple of parameters. I find this works most of the time but sometimes the /ebook/preview is not found and processing drops to the ANY route, in which case the output is similar to this,

```
ANY page 
{:* "/app/preview", :section "50", :id "48"}
```

Can anyone suggest what might cause the /ebook/preview request to be skipped? It is definitely a GET request being made; the HTML does not have a POST for the /app/preview URL and to be doubly sure I added a POST route for /app/preview and that was not being hit.

JAR versions:

```
Clojure 1.2
compojure-0.6.2
ring-core-0.3.7
jetty-6.1.14
ring-jetty-adapter-0.3.1
ring-servlet-0.3.1jar
servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14
```

Routes are wrapped as follows

```
(require '[compojure.handler :as handler])

(defn wrap-charset [handler charset]
  (fn [request]
    (if-let [response (handler request)]
      (if-let [content-type (get-in response [:headers "Content-Type"])]
        (if (.contains content-type "charset")
          response
          (assoc-in response
            [:headers "Content-Type"]
            (str content-type "; charset=" charset)))
        response))))

(def app (-> my-routes
           handler/site
           wrap-stateful-session
           (wrap-charset "utf-8")
           (wrap-file "public")))

(defn run []
  (run-jetty (var app) {:join? false :port 8080}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to figure out what request is causing the problems, stop throwing away the request map with `(request :params)` and just have a look at `request`. That will give you a map with all the information Compojure has; you can inspect it, and pass it back into your routes later to observe what happens (after you make some changes, say).

Comment: Thanks. That's a good suggestion. Still no joy in working out why the correct route doesn't not get picked up but I'll feedback if I work it out.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
(my-preview-function request)
```

returns nil, then the routing will try the next route. Take a look at (source GET) and see how it matches (or doesn't) your route.